# Get class name in attribute definition

Tags: python

I need to make a mixin that knows the name of the class who is using it. Sort of like:

```
class FooMixin(...):
    bar = self.__class__
```

Except that `self` is not defined at attribute definition time. Is there a clean way to achieve this so it's transparent for the class who inherits the mixin?

Comment: That's what `__name__` is for.. `__class__` would be a circular reference, in any case.

Comment: `__name__` holds the module name..not exactly what i need

Comment: I can think of a couple of possibilities to get something like what you want, but can you please elaborate a bit on how you want to *use* this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of definition of your mixin, nobody knows in which classes your mixin is used. You can only get the name dynamically in class methods by using `self.__class__.__name__`:

```
class FooMixin(object):
    def some_method(self):
        print "I'm in class %s" % self.__class__.__name__

class Main(FooMixin):
    pass

instance = Main()
instance.some_method() # "I'm in class Main"
```

Comment: So..can i do a "lazy call" on this method from the definition? Or am i forced to call from the child class?

Comment: Like `name = lambda self: self.__class__.__name__`?

Comment: What do you mean by "lazy"? Can you tell us your actual use-case? There might be solutions, but it's hard to guess if you are that vague.

Comment: With "lazy" i mean "delayed". The problem itself i can solve calling a method from the child class. But if i could put this logic in the parent class, it would become more transparent and more easily reusable.

Comment: I have no idea what I was trying to do 5 years ago :'D
I'm accepting this as the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer gives the reason why this is not possible in the declarative way you seem to like it - nobody knows at Mixin's definition-time where and when it will be used.

However, if you don't care about the time, but want the *syntax*, meaning you want to access bar defined as property in Mixin, and return self.**class**, this should work:

```
class classproperty(object):

    def __get__(self, instance, clazz):
        return clazz

class Mixin(object):

    bar = classproperty()


class Foo(Mixin):
    pass


print Foo().bar
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, no special action is needed to know the name of a class:

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def frob(self):
        print "frobbing a", self.__class__.__name__

class Foo(MyMixin): pass
class Bar(MyMixin): pass
```

```
>>> Foo().frob()
frobbing a Foo
>>> Bar().frob() 
frobbing a Bar
```

similarly, no special action is needed to discover subclasses:

```
>>> MyMixin.__subclasses__()
[__main__.Foo, __main__.Bar]
```

If these aren't what you need, because you want to take action *when* your base class is subclassed, you need a *metaclass!*:

```
class MyMixinMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if bases != (object,):
            print name, cls, "is a subclass of", bases

class MyMixin(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMixinMeta
    def frob(self):
        print "frobbing a", self.__class__.__name__
```

```
>>> class Foo(MyMixin): pass
Foo <class '__main__.Foo'> is a subclass of (<class '__main__.MyMixin'>,)
>>> class Bar(MyMixin): pass
Bar <class '__main__.Bar'> is a subclass of (<class '__main__.MyMixin'>,)
```